# public static method howMany

Tags: java, static

I'm writing a `public static` method `howMany`, which takes as parameters an array of `int`s (nums) and an `int` (value) and returns an `int` (count) of how many times `value` occurs in `nums`.

My code:

```
public static int howMany(int[] nums, int value)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] == value);
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

[The code is not working properly.] I've looked all over my code, I don't know what the issue could be.

Comment: I am guessing this is Java (I added the tag) - am I right?

Comment: Looks good to me... as long as nums is not null.  Oops... as _A.R.S._ has pointed out, you need to get rid of the semi-colon after your if statement.

Answer (score 7):

```
if(nums[i] == value);
```

Remove the ending semi-colon.

Comment: Was I blind? How did I not come to notice?

Comment: I lost two hours on the same exact issue about a month ago.  Was staring at my code for hours saying "am I blind, have I gone insane?"  I took a break, went home, then saw it immediately when I got home.  I think copy/paste was the culprit.

Comment: I feel really dumb for missing that i guess im just worn out.

Comment: @user1818519 Happens to the best of us - especially for small errors like this. Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You have embedded the method in a class File, right? If Not, this might be the issue.